# Client torrent for broadcatching

Tags: leopard, torrent, client

I would like to drop Vuze that I've been running for many years now on my G4 Mac mini in favor of a more lightweight torrent client.

These two features are mandatory:

- Watched folder
- RSS scanner for automatic downloads

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Automatic](http://codingcurious.com/automatic/) (I use 1.x version, which was free, I see there’s version 2.x which is a paid update and I didn’t know about. My 1.x works ok), [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) for the download (it monitors the files that Automatic downloads from a RSS feed I’ve created using [ShowRSS](http://showrss.karmorra.info/) (free).